# What happens when a conflict arises while syncing keychain items?

Tags: ios, keychain

Say I have a randomly generated token I wish to store as a keychain item, with the synchronizable attribute. It's a generic password type, so the primary keys are `kSecAttrService`, `kSecAttrAccount`, and `kSecAttrSynchronizable`. Thus the item's uniqueness is based on these fields.

Say the service and account fields are hard coded by the app, synchronizable as true, and the password being random.

Now say a user has 2 iOS devices with this app, but iCloud Keychain is disabled on both. Each device would store a different token. But these items have the same primary keys, so what happens when iCloud Keychain is enabled on both devices? Would both items be stored on both devices? Or would iCloud Keychain automatically modify so both devices only store one item (the oldest / latest)?

Answer (score 0):

> whichever is most appropriate for the situation

According to [this post](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec0a319b35f/web) both devices will setup a connection to the iCloud server, after which they will store or update the value. It doesn't necessarily say what policy is used to determine which one is preferred over the other.